# Error testing with Spring Boot Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to implement a simple unit test on my service. The code of my test class is the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepoMock;
    private UserService userService;
    private List<User> users;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        userService = new UserService(userRepoMock);

        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setEmail("test@test.com");
        User u2 = new User();
        u2.setEmail("test2@test.com");
        users = Arrays.asList(u1, u2);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAll() throws Exception {
        when(userRepoMock.findAll()).thenReturn(users);

        List<UserDTO> all = userService.getAll(new PageRequest(0, 20));
        verify(userRepoMock).findAll();
    }
}
```

When executing test, I'm always getting an exception, this is an excerpt:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.writer.JsonReaderI
    ...
```

What's wrong in my code? Should I include some dependency not included in `spring-boot-starter-test`?

**Note** I'm using Spring Boot v 1.5.1 and Spring Data MongoDB repositories.

Comment: Is your application starting normally or do you also get these same errors? Using Maven or Gradle for your dependencies?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I'm using Maven and, yes, my application is starting correctly...

Comment: You might want to use the Maven `dependency:tree` command to see if the needed dependency is included. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html Are you running the test from Maven or from your IDE? If from your IDE, did you ensure the latest pom.xml changes are imported?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I discovered to have a dependency conflict in my project: `spring-boot-starter-test` requiring json-smart v2.2.1 and another library (nimbus-jose-jwt) using v 1.3. This is causing the problem...

Comment: Depending on the compability between json-smart 2.2.1 and 1.3 you will need to either add an exclusion or try to get a newer version of nimbus-jose-jwt that also works with json-smart 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

do you use `json-smart-v2`?

There you can see the class in your exception exists:
[Github link](https://github.com/netplex/json-smart-v2/tree/master/json-smart/src/main/java/net/minidev/json/writer)

You have probably a wrong version or some incorrect dependencies.